# how to generate pdf file from php code or print text over image

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

i am working in summer training system project and i want to collect student information by normal html form which will be stored in the database

and i have image for official form which is in PDF file
contains:
name:                  ID:                Company:           etc...

and i want to collect the above data from html form

how to move the collected data then write it on the image(official form)?
can i keep it as pdf after prining ?

i tried to search around but i did not find my ansower

Comment: Look into fPdf. It comes with the PHP install you get with XAMPP. It likely comes with a 'standard' install of PHP - I haven't looked.Also, you can look into GDImage for working just with images. http://www.fpdf.org/ and http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to print on image.

```
<?php
  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('sunset.jpg');

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'font.TTF';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "This is a sunset!";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

You can use [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) library to generate pdf from image